# Cannot get Chrome or IE to open when executing JAR file

Tags: java, selenium, junit, webdriver

How can i run IE and Chrome in my Junit test cases.  Here is the code I have:

import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Selenium_Email_TestCase {

```
private WebDriver driver;
private String baseUrl;
private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("In main method");
    JUnitCore jCore = new JUnitCore();
    jCore.run(Selenium_Email_TestCase.class);
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("In setup");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://stage7.bicycling.com";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
    String jarPath = SeleniumTest.class.getProtectionDomain().
            getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
    File file = new File(jarPath);
    String selHome = file.getParentFile().getParent();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
    selHome+"/web_driver/"+"chromedriver.exe");

   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

You've instantiated your driver, now you just need to have the entry point.  First you need to navigate to the URL to test.

In your `@Before` method (or in your individual tests), you need:

```
driver.get(baseUrl); // or driver.navigate().to(baseUrl);
```

To use Chrome, simply change your instantiation to:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

As you hadn't really elaborated on if you are receiving errors, if you DO receive an error mentioning something about `chromedriver must be set by webdriver.chrome.driver` then you need to set some environment variables, or pass in the variables through your run configuration.  `-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/absolute/path/to/chromedriver`

Comment: Thanks.  We actually decided to stay with Firefox for these regression tests.  It was just easier for the server the program will get ported to.

Comment: did this solve your issue?  You don't seem to have the `.get()`

Comment: I got it to work on my local but it did not work on the server.  Even with the driver installed.   The .get is in test method.  I just did not copy that much of the code.